# Visual Basic : Export Access to Excel Table | VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

My Project is 45% I Need help to convert to export access data to excel spreadsheet,
The "*" is the code im having problem with it, Im Using Visual Studio 2013

Im going to export access 2013 table to excel 2013.

'EXPORTS TABLE IN ACCESS DATABASE TO EXCEL

```
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim strWorksheet As String
    Dim strDB As String
    Dim strTable As String
    * Dim objDB As Database

    strExcelFile = "|DataDirectory|\ExportedData.xls"
    strWorksheet = "WorkSheet1"
    strDB = "C:\My Documents\MyDatabase.mdb"
    strTable = "MyTable"

    * objDB = OpenDatabase(strDB)

    If Dir(strExcelFile) <> "" Then Kill(strExcelFile)

    objDB.Execute _
      "SELECT * INTO [Excel 8.0;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & _
       "].[" & strWorksheet & "] FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]"
    objDB.Close()
    objDB = Nothing
```

---

**NEW CODE**

Having error on acExport, What do you think this variable is used for.

<

```
    Dim objDB As Object
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim strWorksheet As String
    Dim strDB As String
    Dim strTable As String
    strExcelFile = "|DataDirectory|\ExportedData.xls"
    strWorksheet = "sheet1"
    strDB = "|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdb"
    strTable = "MyTable"

    objDB.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDB)
    objDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acExport, 8, strTable, strExcelFile, True, strWorksheet)

    objDB.CloseCurrentDatabase()
    objDB = Nothing
```

>

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objDB = OpenDatabase(strDB)
```

You should use Set when assigning a value to an object-type variable

Comment: It worked. But I Used for now is objDB.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDB). The 2nd Error is  objDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acExport, 8, strTable, strExcelFile, True, strWorksheet)  Im Having error on acExport,